# Do Preludes affect new investigators

Tags: eldritch-horror

When an Investigator is Defeated the player chooses a new investigator at the end of the Mythos Phase.

If the [Otherworldly Dreams](https://eldritchhorror.fandom.com/wiki/Otherworldly_Dreams) Prelude is in play

> After resolving setup, if Hypnos is the Ancient One, each Investigator loses 1 Health and 1 Sanity and gains 1 Focus. Then, each investigator may spend 1 Health and 1 Sanity to gain 1 Clue.

Is the new investigator affected by this?

What about Preludes that say "Before step", like [Call of Cthulhu](https://eldritchhorror.fandom.com/wiki/Call_of_Cthulhu)

> Before step 9 of setup ("Resolve Starting Effects), each investigator
> moves to the nearest Sea space and loses 1 Sanity. If Cthulhu is the
> Ancient One, each investigator places 1 Eldritch token on the nearest
> Sea space that does not contain an Eldritch Token
>
> If Cthulhu is not the Ancient One, set aside 1 Deep One Monster and
> spawn the Cthylla Epic Monster on space 3.
>
> Then, each investigator may spend 1 Sanity to gain 1 Clue.

What about [Epidemic](https://eldritchhorror.fandom.com/wiki/Epidemic), how much of that would be resolved?

> After resolving setup, if Abhoth is the Ancient One, each Investigator spawns 1 Cultist Monster on a Wilderness space that does not contain a Cultist Monster.
>
> If Abhoth is not the Ancient One, the Lead Investigator spawn the Child of Abhoth Epic Monster on the nearest Wilderness space.
>
> Then, each Investigator gains 1 Illness Condition and 1 Clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the Prelude cards would apply. The Prelude cards specified timing is either Setup or After Setup and drawing a new investigator is during gameplay.

> When playing with this expansion, players draw one random Prelude card before setting up the game. These cards **alter game setup** and make each game feel unique.
> The card’s effect is resolved immediately after drawing the card, unless it specifies **different timing**, such as “after resolving setup.”
>
> - [Mountains of Madness Rules; Page 4](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/45/6f/456fd74f-d9b0-4ffd-98c1-2348ae297e34/eh03-rulebook.pdf)

The Setup and After Setup Prelude cards are one-time effects that alter the beginning of the game. During gameplay, when you would draw a new investigator, is after both of these timings.